# Problem in Next13 with Server and Client components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server, client

I'm working on a Next.js 13 app. I have my page like this:

```
export default async function Page({ params }: { params: { lang: ValidLocale } }) {
    return (
        <>
            <Selectors> // Client Component
                <CustomList filters={filters} /> // Server Component
            </Selectors>
        </>
    )
}
```

Depending on the filters I have in Selectors, I need to pass them to CustomList. The documentation says that you can't import a Server Component inside a Client Component, and this is the recommended way to do it.

CustomList needs to be server-rendered because I load all the products on a main page, and I have another one for searching with filters. Should they be different components? Can't they be reused?

Thank you very much, and greetings!